# Desenho através de um .txt

Tags: java, 2d

Estou com uma grande dúvida de como passar os dados do método leituraArquivo2D para as variáveis hairX e hairY, no leituraArquivo2D ele percorre um arquivo populando vx e vy com os valores do .txt, alguém pode me dar uma luz de como fazer isso?

Segue a classe abaixo:

```
public class Monalisa extends JFrame {
Polygon hair;
int[] hairX=new int[15];
int[] hairY=new int[15];

public Monalisa(){
        hair = new Polygon(hairX,hairY,15);
        setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        repaint();
    }

    public static boolean leituraArquivo2D(String arquivo, int vx[],int vy[]){
        try{
            FileReader arq = new FileReader(arquivo);
            BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);

            String linha = lerArq.readLine();

            int id=0;
            while((linha=lerArq.readLine())!=null){
                String vetXY[]=linha.split(" ");
                vx[id]=Integer.parseInt(vetXY[0]);
                vy[id]=Integer.parseInt(vetXY[1]);
                id=id+1;
            }
            arq.close();
            return true;

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Erro na abertura do arquivo:"+arquivo);
        return false;
    }


}


    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRoundRect(147, 84, 103, 74,23,23);
        g.fillOval(147, 94, 103, 132);

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillPolygon(hair);

        int[] eyebrow1X={151,168,174,171,178,193};
        int[] eyebrow1Y={145,140,148,184,191,188};
        g.drawPolyline(eyebrow1X, eyebrow1Y, 6);

        int[] eyebrow2X={188,197,213,223};
        int[] eyebrow2Y={146,141,142,146};
        g.drawPolyline(eyebrow2X, eyebrow2Y, 4);

        int[] mouthX={166,185,200};
        int[] mouthY={199,200,197};
        g.drawPolyline(mouthX, mouthY, 3);

        g.fillOval(161, 148, 10, 3);
        g.fillOval(202, 145, 12, 5);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Monalisa mona = new Monalisa();
        mona.setSize(400, 400);
        mona.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, terá de definir as variáveis `hairX` e `hairY` como `static`:

```
static int[] hairX = new int[15];
static int[] hairY = new int[15];
```

Então basta chamar a função `leituraArquivo2D` passando os parâmetros necessários a partir da Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  boolean b = leituraArquivo2D("C:\abc.txt", hairX, hairY);
  /*
  ...
  */
}
```

Comment: sabe me dizer o por que do static?

Comment: 1º Porque você está dentro da main (static, *métodos statics só podem acessar variaveis e outros métodos statics de forma direta). 2º Para garantir que a variável vai ser única na memória, assim ela própria será alterada dentro do método que recebeu ela por parâmetro.